# error: <identifier> expected in java hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, java-7, bigdata

I'm compiling a java file for word count hadoop, but when it's compiling it throws an error:

> CountBook.java:33: error: expected public void reduce(Text_key,Iteratorvalues,OutputCollectoroutput,Reporter reporter)throws IOException

this is my code

```
public class CountBook
{
    public static class EMapper extends MapReducebase implements
    Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>
    {
        private final static Intwritable one = new Intwritable(1);
        public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable>output,Reporter reporter)throws IOException
        {
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] Data = line.split("\";\"");
            output.collect(new text(Data[0]),one);

        }
    }


public static class EReduce extends MapReduceBase implements
Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>
{
    public void reduce(Text_key,Iterator<IntWritable>values,OutputCollector<text,intWritable>output,Reporter reporter)throws IOException
    {
        Text key=_key;
        int authid=0;
        while(values.hasNext())
        {
            IntWritable value = (IntWritable)values.next();
            authid+=value.get();
        }
        output.collect(key,new intWritable(authid));
    }
}


public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
    JobConf conf = new JbConf(CountBook.class);
    conf.setjobName("CountBookByAuthor");
    conf.setOutputkeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    conf.setMapperClass(EMapper.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(EReduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(EReducer.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf,new path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path(args[1]));
    JobCLient.runJob(conf);
}
}
```

I'm using hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar for classpath library and running in centos 7

Comment: It looks like you are trying to embed public lasses within public classes - can not do this as every public class needs to be in its own file

Answer (score 1):

You currently have:

```
reduce(Text_key, 
       Iterator<IntWritable>values,
       OutputCollector<text,intWritable>output, 
       Reporter reporter)
```

It should be:

```
reduce(Text key, 
       Iterator<IntWritable> values,
       OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, 
       Reporter reporter)
```

The main differences being `key` needs a space between it and `Text` and the types in `OutputCollector<>` need to be capatilized.